# What are these brown stains on my Bougainvillea's leaves?

Tags: identification, diagnosis, flowers, plant-health, diseases

I recently got this Bougainvillea from a vivarium but I've noticed there are some brown stains in its leaves, just on the bottom of the plant. Do you know what these are, and how I should treat it?

For reference, it's in the garden, under a roof, with enough sunlight but not direct. For now, I have it isolated from the other plants, just in case.

Also, the bracts that cover the flowers are somewhat wrinkled, is that okay?
(pictures attached).

[image: Leaves stained, at the bottom of the plant]

[image: the wrinkled bracts, around the flowers]

Comment: Yes you would need more sunlight but that is not the problem. I have the same issue. I live in FL...we get plenty of sun and live in a tropical climate which they thrive on. They are not over or under-watered either. I keep them fertilized as well on a regular basis....this has to somehow be related to a disease or fungus....but how to fix this is the question. A standard anti-fungal is not working either.

Answer (score 2):

Those brown areas look like regions of leaf necrosis so there has been some stress to the plant which could be watering, warmth, light etc.

Answer (score 1):

Bougainvilleas should receive plenty of direct sunlight daily, according to my experience. They thrive in the scorching sun here in Singapore (8hrs at temp >34C) and bloom profusely after 2 weeks of no rain.

I would guess that insufficient light as the top reason in addition to Graham Chiu's response.